# Are custom handlers (used only on specific urls) idiomatic in go

Tags: go, handler, middleware

Is it good practice in golang to write custom handlers used just in specific endpoints?

I.e. given following endpoint: `/users/someusername/items/1` I know I'll need user information (for user with id: `someusername`) and also information for item with id: `1`. Would it be good practice to create 2 custom handlers, one which will handle pulling user data and putting it in context (and exit on error with proper response) and another one for pulling item data (and also putting it in context to use by further handlers)? 
And then using them as follow:

```
userItemsHandler := userContextHandler(itemConextHandler(ItemGET))
r.Handle("/users/{username}/items/{itemId}", userItemsHandler).Methods("PUT")
```

In example, custom handler for items will be probably used in only couple endpoints, though I can see multiple usage for user handler.

Thanks in advance for answers.

Comment: No, it's not idiomatic to put data into context. Yes, it is idiomatic to create endpoint specific handlers.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for answer! Could you please elaborate on why it is not idiomatic to use context to pass data to further handlers/middlewares? I didn't found such information in https://golang.org/pkg/context/ . As I'm starting with golang, all insight would be helpful! Thanks!

Comment: It is in the first paragraph of the documentation you linked, although it's not very exact and it only states what the context is intended to carry and not what it should not, and so it is easy to overlook. If you need more info you can google "what to put into golang context" and you'll see a bunch of articles thay may be useful, for example: https://dave.cheney.net/2017/08/20/context-isnt-for-cancellation and the linked articles in it should be of value to you.

Comment: Context is generally a very poor mechanism for storing/transfering data (due to implementation complexity and loss of type safety), and is best used for cancellation only if possible.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! Probably question for another thread, but is there any other way to move data down to final handler? In most cases, I'll need user details, which I was expecting to grab in first middleware, right after auth check.

Comment: Many ways. One that has served me well is creating a "request handler" type to store request-specific details in a type-safe way. Each request gets a new instance created, and the actual handlers are implemented as methods on this type.